# Expected identifier error when calling a singleton method iOS

Tags: ios, methods, syntax, singleton, call

I'm trying to call a method from a class that uses a singleton pattern on a different class. I'm using a tutorial that doesn't use a singleton that works great, but I can't seem to implement what I need. I keep getting an error that says Expected identifier. I'm assuming this is probably due to syntax, but I can't seem to resolve it. The POI is an NSManagedObject subclass from core data.

This is my version using a singleton. The error points at the bracket before DataSource.

```
NSArray *itemGroups = [POI [DataSource sharedInstance] fetchDistinctItemGroupsInManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

Here is the equivalent (from the tutorial) without a singleton

```
NSArray *itemGroups = [POI fetchDistinctItemGroupsInManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want be able to use `POI` class in this way:

```
NSArray *itemGroups = [POI fetchDistinctItemGroupsInManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

then I will suggest to add such code:

```
// POI.h
+ (NSArray *)fetchDistinctItemGroupsInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;

// POI.m
+ (NSArray *)fetchDistinctItemGroupsInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    return [[DataSource sharedInstance] fetchDistinctItemGroupsInManagedObjectContext: context];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have somethig like: `[[POI sharedInstance] fetchDistinctItemGroupsInManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];`

Comment: I thought about this, but I'm concerned about breaking other parts of my application. There's no other work around for this?

Comment: It's the default way to get a singleton and call it. You have a classe called `POI` and wants to get the `sharedInstance` (singleton). You should prepare your app to deal with this. Its is the correct way.

Comment: The only problem is that fetchDistinctItemGroupsInManagedObjectContext: is defined in my data source, I just cant seem to call it on POI.